Remix IDE: My code compiles, but I still get red space in the first line, it says "Invalid EVM version requested". How to remove this warning?

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.19;


contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 myFavoriteNumber;

    struct Person {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    // uint256[] public anArray;
    Person[] public listOfPeople;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        myFavoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return myFavoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        listOfPeople.push(Person(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    }
}


Can you try clearing browser cache and see if the warning still persists?

i tried but smae problem , even if there is no code its red     SYED ASAD KAZMI

What compiler version are you using from the dropdown?

0.8.19 , when i tried higher higher versions red line disappeared  but from 0.8.24 and higher

Okay, and what is the EVM version, which is there in the Advanced Configurations section just below the compiler version selection?

default version and in the Deploy & run transactions the default selected is remix vm cancun

Can you try changing the EVM version to paris?

it worked in   0.8.19 thanks , but why ?

I've added some explanation in my answer. Please check.

As you’re using the Solidity compiler version 0.8.19, you must select an EVM version from paris or below.

Similarly, for compiler versions from 0.8.20 to 0.8.23, you can use the shanghai EVM version.
And, for compiler versions from 0.8.24 to 0.8.27, you can use the cancun EVM version.

thanks you for your help

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
